# How to run a bat script on remote windows system after successful ssh using ansible

Tags: windows, ansible, cygwin, ansible-2.x

I am trying to run a batch file with an argument on a remote windows machine from my local Cygwin console using Ansible. I have successfully configured ssh to a remote windows machine using OpenSSH. If I run this ansible command, I get this output.

> ansible -i inventory.yml -m win_ping windows_server1 -vvv

```
windows_server1 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "data": "pong"
        }
    },
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

My inventory file is as below.

```
---
all:
  hosts:
    windows_server1:
      ansible_connection: ssh
      ansible_shell_type: cmd
      ansible_host: "host1"
      ansible_user: "user1@DOMAIN"
```

Now when I add a playbook to execute a batch file with arguments, I get an error. Tried script, win_command, win_shell, win_psexec modules with no luck. Here is the code in my playbook.

```
---
- hosts: windows_server1
  become: yes
  become_method: runas
  become_user: user1
  tasks:
    - name: Invoke App stop script
      win_command:
        cmd: '"D:\Temp\appstop.bat" "argument 1" -stop'
```

Here is the ansible command I used.

> ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml playbook-01.yml -vvv

Here is the error I am getting now.

> fatal: [windows_server1]: FAILED! => {
> "changed": false,
> "msg": "Get-AnsibleParam: Missing required argument: _raw_params" }

Appreciate any hints to proceed with this. Thanks

Comment: I have never worked with ansible, but my gut feeling is the string should be written as `cmd: "D:\\Temp\\appstop.bat \"argument 1\" -stop"`. This assumes that the first argument to the batch file,  _argument 1_,  must really be those two words, _argument_ and _1_, separated by one space.

Comment: Thank you! but no luck with this syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code snippet

```yaml
- name: Run a bat script on remote windows system after successful ssh using ansible
  hosts: windows
  tasks:
    - name: Run a bat script on remote windows system after successful ssh using ansible
      win_shell: C:\Users\test\test.bat
      register: result
      ignore_errors: yes
    - name: Display output
      debug:
        var: result.stdout_lines
```

Comment: This worked like magic. I am guessing ignore_errors played a key role. Is there an option to close out ssh connection after each execution to ensure open connections are not causing occasional ssh connection refused errors?

Comment: Great! Yes `ignore_errors` is an error handling directive in ansible. For ssh connections you can refer [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html)